# Regex matching optional pattern/string

Tags: python, regex

I have a list of strings, and I'm trying to write regex that captures groups of strings that may or may not contain a certain pattern.

```
 any ascii character string
another string = other stuff
string = another string = string
```

I'm trying to capture the part of the string before first occurrence of the pattern (`" = "`) and after the pattern. I've tried this:

```
\s*?([\x00-\x7F]+)( - )?(.*)?
```

but then it just captures the entire string as one group.
How would I do this?

Comment: So you want `[['another string', 'other stuff'], ['string', 'another string = string']]`?

Comment: @poke I guess it would be more like `[['any ascii character string'], ['another string', 'other stuff'], ['string', 'another string = string']]` because I want the first result to match as well

Answer (score 0):

You *can* solve this with regular expressions:

```
>>> text = '''any ascii character string
another string = other stuff
string = another string = string'''

>>> re.findall('^([^=]+?)(?: = (.*?))?$', text, re.M)
[('any ascii character string', ''),
 ('another string ', ' other stuff'),
 ('string ', ' another string = string')]
```

But in this case, a lot easier would be to just split by line and then partition/split the line by the first equals character:

```
>>> [line.split('=', 1) for line in text.splitlines()]
[['any ascii character string'],
 ['another string ', ' other stuff'],
 ['string ', ' another string = string']]
```

If you don’t like that whitespace, just strip it away:

```
>>> [list(map(str.strip, line.split('=', 1))) for line in text.splitlines()]
[['any ascii character string'],
 ['another string', 'other stuff'],
 ['string', 'another string = string']]
```

Comment: Thanks!! I forgot to mention that sometimes the `"="` character is also in the string e.g., `some str=ing = something`. I think I'd just use the pythonic way, but I was wondering if the problem could still be solved with regex?

Comment: How do you differentiate between those `=` then? Just by spaces around them? If those are required, then just includes those in the `split` call.